# Where can you find possible key combinations and their outputs?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, i3-wm

So... I recently bought a keyboard with a US layout as they didn't have it for my native language. It is however missing the key on the keyboard where i normally do '\'. I am using I3 as my WM and ubuntu 18.04. Is there a way to check different combinations of keys does? I seem to recall it is in some file, and can also be changed there, but cant find that file...

EDIT:
The problem is, that on the US keybhoard the key next to Z is SHIFT. Normally there is a key before shift, where backslash is on danish layouts. I want to see if some combination of keys on the US keyboard corresponds to this missing key... Or remap something to backslash alternatively.

Comment: What do you mean the '\' key is missing? On the us layout AFAIR has the '\' between the enter and backspace key?

Comment: @j-money Bad explanation sorry. I purchased a keyboard with US layout. I then set the keyboard layout as DK in ubuntu. From here i can't type  '\' as the key i normally use on a native DK layout keyboard is missing.

Comment: Try <Right Alt>+[key to the left of Z]. But you can show the keyboard layout, for instance by going to _Region & Language_, selecting the Danish layout, and clicking the keyboard icon.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson The problem is, that on the US keybhoard i have the key next to Z is SHIFT. Normally there is a key  before shift, where backslash is on danish layouts. I want to see if some combination of keys on the US keyboard corresponds to this missing key... Or remap something to backslash alternatively.

Comment: Actually the US keyboard layout includes an ordinary key to the left of the Z key, so it seems like the physical keyboard you bought isn't optimal, neither for English (US) nor Danish.

Comment: Woops, it seems you are right. Its a happy hacking keyboard, but i just assumed all US layouts were like that, but this seems to be different. Strange.

Comment: Although, this seems to be a us layout, without a key next to Z http://kbd-intl.narod.ru/images/en.png

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this? It just reads in from the keyboard and echo's it back out!

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>
//All other includes
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char getkey()
{
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval timev;
    int ioready;
    char ch;
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(0, &rfds);

    timev.tv_sec = 0;
    timev.tv_usec = 0;

    ioready = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &timev);

    if(ioready)
    {
        read(1, &ch, 1);
        return ch;
    }
    else
        return '\0';
}

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        char my_char = getkey();
        if(my_char == 'q')
            break;
        printf("%c", my_char);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash on my keyboard that looks like the one in the picture you posted is obtained by pressing shift+(the key before number 1).

> "Or remap something to backslash alternatively."

You could use Xmodmap, xkb or AutoKey to remap keys. With xbindkeys you can launch a command with a combination of keys. I don't know how to remap keys with it.

With AutoKey, a graphical user interface (GUI), you can use abbreviations. For example, to obtain a backslash you can type "zz" or use a hotkey ctrl+y or whatever combination you want (Control, Alt, Shift, Super, Hyper, Meta).

Danish and Norwegian alphabet :

- aae to æ
- AAE to Æ
- OO  to Ø

Other examples :

- btw   to by the way
- addd  to a multiline address
- tilde to ~ ...

There are also sample scripts in python (insert date with an abbreviation or a hotkey). And you can code your own.

A Python3 version is on GitHub. https://github.com/autokey/autokey

Or an outdated version in the Sofware Manager. This version may freeze when configuring data. Sometimes I had to open the terminal and write : xkill ; than click on AutoKey window.

To set a hotkey you have to do theses steps in the right order :

Hotkey/Set/Press to Set/Press a key.../Press Ctrl or Alt or Shift/Ok ; Then Save