# unable to configure italian keyboard with ISO layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have just bought a new keyboard: HP omen 1100 italian layout. It is an ANSI keyboard with italian labels on it. I'm not able to correctly configure the keyboard in ubuntu 18. The closest layout I was able to find is the italian layout. All keys work as expected but one: the '<' key is usually located (on ISO keyboards) between the left shift and the z key. However the ANSI layout has no key there (the shift key is larger) and instead the '<' sign is marked on the key between the right Fn and Ctrl keys where in the US layout one has the "menu" key. But if I press such key I get the 'menu' key as I would get with the US layout.

I've tried all layout proposed in the "italian" menu... no one is working.

Comment: This problem seems to be similar to https://askubuntu.com/q/1084666 . I don't know how to best deal with it, though.

Answer (score 0):

My solution so far:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 135 = less greater"
```

this changes the key mapping of the "menu" key to match the layout of my keyboard.

It's not clear to me if this solution is permanent and what happens if I mix this with the keyboard selection of ubuntu configuration.